# WPF - styling a listviewitem with the mouse over it - weird box shows up

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I’m trying to style the items in my listview.  I have the items contained in a WrapPanel and I’ve added some styling to the ListViewItems.  When the mouse hovers over an item, the item turns yellow.  However, there is this stupid box that shows up around my item and I’ve not been able to figure out where it is coming from so I can either hide it or make it yellow too.  Can somebody throw me a hint?
Here is what my item looks like:
[image]

The styling I'm using is this:

```
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Office2010BlueButtonHighlightAndPressedForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
```

The ListView markup:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ResultsViewGrid}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
                    <Grid Width="320">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="," VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 2 0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
```

...snipped out for brevity

Can somebody tell me what particular property controls that box?  I think its the focus box, but I have not found it yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: focus box is a dotted rectangle.  I believe that is the mouseover behavior for the built in listviewitem, or maybe the row presenter itself?  are you extending the existing listviewitem style (using BasedOn)?  or overriding it completely?  (your top box of style stuff just shows the trigger)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the `Border` inside the `ListViewItem`'s `ControlTemplate`.

That default template has a set of triggers that sets the background and foreground on hover, selection, etc.

you might be able to "cheat" by giving your template a negative margin to cover that up?

here's an example from the msdn docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788717(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the ListItem's control template there is a Border whose color you are viewing.
Change the border brush property to the color you wish and the problem is resolved